# A rather big C++ open source project, easy to reach and easy to build with MinGW?

Tags: c++, open-source, build, mingw

I am looking for an open source project whom:
 - is easy to test with cppunit, then not a GUI program, otherwise with a CLI (command line interface),
 - is written in C++,
 - is rather big,
 - easy to reach,
 - easy to build with MinGW (on Windows platform),
Thanks

Comment: http://www.boost.org or http://qt.nokia.com/, but this is barely a question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of larger C++ open-source projects which I know of and which support MinGW:

- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) - Cross-platform GUI (and non-GUI) toolkit, has historically excellent support for MinGW
- [ITK](http://www.itk.org) - An image processing library
- [VTK](http://www.vtk.org) - A visualization library
- [CTK](http://www.commontk.org) - Provides common libraries and tools for the medical imaging community